# Restify and React : how to serve correctly as Express?

Tags: deployment, react-router-v4, create-react-app, restify

I have developped an app with create react app and i want to deploy it. React is used for the front end and Restify publish API that is consumed by the front end.

The app uses browser history and when i refresh the page Restify return JSON object saying that the route is unknown.

To solve this problem, the Create-react-app documentation explains how to do it well with the Express server :

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Here is the doc :
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment

Use Case
As mentionned in the create-react-app doc, i use restify to serve static front end React app :

```
server.get(
  /\/(.*)?.*/,
  restify.plugins.serveStatic({
    directory: "./static",
    default: "index.html"
  })
);
```

It's all right with Express but not with Restify. With Express, we must use a middleware first to server static files and next we have to redirect routes to the "index.html" front end app.
With Restify, i have just only used the serveStatic plugin, but it's not enough.

So, if you have an idea to solve that... it would be fabulous !
thx

Comment: can you try to access that file when directly from the browser?

Comment: the static files are served corectly (css, js, index.html); the React app runs well and the push history browser is ok; but refreshing page breaks things. May be index.html can't be traited as a static file ?